Why hasn't the percentage of renewable electricity grown in Germany this year?
A large German newspaper, Die Zeit, has been showing a daily-updated energy infographic on its front page for a few years now. Today, in the summer of 2024, the graphic looks like this:

 see * if you don't understand German 
As you can see in the third panel, the percentage of renewable electricity in 2024 started out higher than in 2023, but plateaued out at the 2023 level for the past few months. At the same time, there has been 10.1 GW of wind and solar capacity added since beginning of the year (first and second panel). And the graphic doesn't show it, but there also has been capacity added between August and December 2023, so in total, it's more than these 10.1 GW.
I find it surprising that this year, Germany is not producing a larger percentage of renewable electricity despite the added capacity. Also, this isn't visible in the graphic, but I remember that last year, the then-current state of the infographic showed a noticeable increase in the percentage of renewable energy between 2022 and 2023.
Of course there are plausible explanations of what might cause this; I can think of several different ones. What I would like to see is an evidence-based answer of what is actually happening.

*  The screenshot is labelled in German, but the information relevant to my question is actually contained in a few numbers and the curves in the third panel. The first two panels show us that Germany built 1.1 GW worth of wind parks and 9.0 GW worth of solar parks since 1.1.2024, the third panel is the percentage of electricity produced by renewable energy in 2023 and 2024, with 68% being the average of the last 30 days, and the last panel shows that the daily production in Germany is 1 TWh (this is for a single day, but the variation between days isn't too large). 

I assume weather and maintenance (last year was not so easy to shut down, but now with more secure gas, things may be better). (why I say so? check wind: much below expectations). But for evidence based answer: you should do own research: when there are so many actors, it is often impossible to find a good summary

All the data needed to answer this question are available here: https://transparency.entsoe.eu/. I suspect there are a number of factors related to capacity and demand. I probably won't have time to pull together an answer but someone with some time could start there.
